# Is it possible for a probability density function to have jump continuities?

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-distributions

For example, if I have a probability density function $f(t)$, which is defined within the range of $[0,2]$ (i.e., $f(t)=0$ if $t>2$). If we knows that $f(t)=C$ ($C$ is a positive constant number, but unknown) in the range of $[0,2)$, is it possible that a jump discontinuity occurs at $t=2$ (i.e., $f(2)\neq C$)?

Moreover, if we know that in the above question $C=\frac{1}{2}$, is it possible that $f(2)\neq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes it's possible for probability densities to have discontinuities. Typically, all you need is $f(t)\ge 0$ for all relevant $t$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) dt = 1$.

Comment: "Jump continuities"? If that's a typo in the title, perhaps you would consider editing it. And if it's not a typo, perhaps you would consider explaining it.

Comment: Please engage with the comments and answers that have been posted, Erik.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are dealing with likelihood functions in statistics, the value of a probability density at a given countable number of points doesn't matter because the density is always used inside an integral. The following functions
$$f(t) = \begin{cases} 1/2 & t \in [0, 2] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$f(t) = \begin{cases} 1/2 & t \in [0, 2) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$f(t) = \begin{cases} 1/2 & t \in [0, 2) \\ 10 & t=2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$f(t) = \begin{cases} 1/2 & t \in [0, 2] \setminus \{1/4, 1/2, 3/4\} \\ 100  & t \in \{1/4, 1/2, 3/4\}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
etc. all are the "same" density function because
$$\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = \frac{1}{2} (\min\{2, b\} - \max\{0, a\}),$$ regardless of which $f$ you chose.

Answer (score 2):

The examples provided by @angryavian should have already answered your question. I'd like to add some more.

A density function corresponding to the distribution function $F$ of a random variable X is defined to be **any** non-negative function satisfying $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \, \lambda(dt) \quad \forall~x\in\mathbb{R}$$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Note that $X$ may not have a unique density (or, in fact, any density at all). If you can somehow guarantee that it has at least one density (say $f$), any non-negative function $g$ satisfying $f=g~ \lambda$-a.e. will be another density function. Thus you can produce a lot more of them by tweaking $f$ on a set $\mathcal{D}$ as long as you can ensure that $\mathcal D$ has $\lambda$-measure $0$.

In your problem, the support is $[0,2]$. Thus, whatever be your density $f$ on $[0,2)$, you can always tweak $f$ at $x=2$ to ensure that it has a jump discontinuity at $x=2$. Given all these, you should be able to answer your next question by yourself. Hope it helps!

Comment: So can we say that f(2) can be any value, if we have f(t)=1/2 for any t\in [0,2) ?